# Strange behavior from custom scrollbar?

Tags: css, frontend, webkit

I add the following code to customize my scroll bars, but it is not applied uniformly.  In this example the page scroll bar reacts to both color and width but the div scroll bar only reacts to color.

How can I get the div scroll bar to react to the width.  I'm in Chrome.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `height: 5px;` property on `::-webkit-scrollbar`

Comment: I see the width is always on the x-axis, even if the orientation of the scroll bar changes ... falafel balls!